# Reading attributes only using ogr2ogr

Tags: gdal, ogr

I'm trying to use `ogr2ogr` to extract some attributes from a Shapefile to a `netCDF`. I can limit which attributes are read using the `-select` argument, but it seems that the geometry is written to the output file no matter what. Is there some way to exclude the geometry using `ogr2ogr` ?

```
ogr2ogr -f "NetCDF" /tmp/ogrout.nc \
        -dsco "FORMAT=NC4C" \
        -select "HYBAS_ID, NEXT_DOWN" \
        /tmp/basins.shp
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the -sql option of ogr2ogr together with the SQLite SQL dialect https://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql_sqlite.html

```
ogr2ogr -f "NetCDF" /tmp/ogrout.nc \
        -dsco "FORMAT=NC4C" \
        -dialect SQLite \      
        -sql "select HYBAS_ID, NEXT_DOWN from basins" \
        /tmp/basins.shp
```